# Boto3 returns An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I've created a user with a policy having full access to S3:
[image]

When I set credentials (~/.aws/credentials) and try to push a file to my bucket using boto3, it returns `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`

Any idea why is this happening?

I've even tried generating an access key id / secret access key for the root account and it returns the same error. I've run my code with another account's credentials and it works fine, so the issue is within the account itself.

EDIT:

I verified that the caller ID is the same as my account using `boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')`.

I don't have a policy set for my bucket, and these are its permissions
[image]

This is a snippet of my class

```
from boto3 import client
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from boto3.exceptions import S3UploadFailedError

class AmazonS3(object):
    s3 = client('s3')

@classmethod
def upload_image(cls, bucket_name, object_name, file_content):
    extra_args = {"ACL": "public-read",
                  "ContentType": "image/jpeg" if object_name.split('.')[-1] in ['jpg', 'jpeg'] else "image/png",
                  "ContentDisposition": "inline",
                  "ContentEncoding": "base64"}

    try:
        cls.s3.put_object(Body=file_content, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_name, **extra_args)
    except (ClientError, S3UploadFailedError, Exception) as e:
        raise Exception('There was an error when uploading the image')
```

Comment: Try `aws sts get-caller-identity` and ensure the call is made by the right principal. Is there a bucket policy on the bucket? Please include any policies you set up in JSON form.

Comment: Does it work if you try to copy the file using the AWS CLI?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes

Comment: If it works from the AWS CLI but not from boto3 and both of those are using the same credentials, then the error probably lies in your Python code. Can you include a minimally-reproducible example in your Question?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've edited my question. I should note that this code has been working for months in another environment, I test any credentials locally by setting them in my docker-compose file. Old credentials work, new ones unfortunately don't. But I've tried *aws s3 cp* inside the container and it's working

Comment: If one set of credentials work and one don't, then it suggests that the problem lies with the permissions associated with the credentials (that don't work), or it is not using the credentials you think it is!

Comment: I've verified the caller identifier and it's the same as my account with a problem. I've also called boto3's *list_buckets()* and it returns the buckets in my account, but *put_object* returns Access Denied when I try to put an object to my bucket, which already works using *aws cli* and another set of credentials, but not these ones which belong to a user that precisely has a *PutObject* in their policy. Does this even make sense?

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue. In my code I'm getting the bucket name from an environment variable like this `os.getenv('AWS_BUCKET_NAME', 'X')`.

In my deployment I've set *BUCKET_NAME='Y'* as environment variable, so it made sense to be able to list my S3 buckets and get 'Y' in the output and not be able to upload a file, to 'X' not 'Y' since `AWS_BUCKET_NAME` was not set during the deployment.

But the error `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied` is misleading and is stating that I don't have the right permissions instead of stating that the bucket may not exist.

Comment: thanks for answering this for yourself, it solved my problem immediately! Pretty lame that they haven't fixed this error message in the interceding two years...

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem here as well. That error message is not helpful at all!